# Documentation event listeners

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have a question concerning this code down here:

```
on.("click", () => {...})
```

Currently I try to figure out Electron. In a code example I saw the use of the usual event listener function. In the fat-arrow function the developer used different kinds of properties. For example:

```
on.("click", () => {event, bounds})
```

I am interested in the amount of properties you can use... there are probably more than just those two. I could not find any documentation on this.
That did not help me at all: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/click

Maybe someone can help me out on this.

Comment: Do you mean `.on(`? - `{event, bounds}` would both be undefined.

Comment: @evolutionxbox `event` or `window.event` is global and has the currently handled event (except in Firefox). `bounds` would be undefined though.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, what confused you is - [Desctructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).
This code(which is not very correct):

```
.on("click", () => {event, bounds})
```

Can be overwritten by this one:

```
.on("click", e => {
  return {
    event: e.event, 
    bounds: e.bounds
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am interested in the amount of properties you can use...

There are no other properties besides the ones embedded into the event object.

`event` refers to the global variable `window.event` which is a reference to the currently handled event.

```
.on('click', () => { console.log(event) })
```

and

```
.on('click', (e) => { console.log(e) })
```

will output the same event (exept in Firefox, where the first example will not output anything)

I highly suspect that `bounds` is a variable defined by the author of your tutorial, because the click-event doesn't have a direct `bounds` property (as you've already seen in the MDN documentation). We'd have to see the full example to explain it where it actually comes from.